# Sending message from plugin to form not working for empty values

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm sending a custom message from a plugin (that does some validation) back to the CRM form.

Here's my plugin code that executes on pre-Update and post-Create:

```
//GetAccounts is a simple method to return accounts based in specified crtitias. 
//In Update event, it will add an extra filter to exclude the current account...
const string DupeFieldName = "new_approval_status";

if (xrmObjects.PluginContext.PrimaryEntityName == Xrm.Account.EntityLogicalName && xrmObjects.PluginContext.Depth == 1 && (xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName == "Update" || xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName == "Create"))
{
    Entity account;
    account = (Entity)xrmObjects.PluginContext.InputParameters["Target"];

    if (account.Attributes.Contains("name"))
    {
        if (GetAccounts(account, xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName, "name", account["name"], xrmObjects.Service).Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            SetDupeMessage(account, Name);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (account.Attributes.Contains("websiteurl"))
    {
        if (GetAccounts(account, xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName, "websiteurl", account["websiteurl"], xrmObjects.Service).Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            SetDupeMessage(account, WebSiteExist);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (account.Attributes.Contains("new_linkedin"))
    {
        if (GetAccounts(account, xrmObjects.PluginContext.MessageName, "new_linkedin", account["new_linkedin"], xrmObjects.Service).Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            SetDupeMessage(account, LinkedIn);
            return;
        }
    }


    account[DupeFieldName] = string.Empty;

}
```

The simple method that sets the attributes' value...

```
private void SetDupeMessage(Entity account, string message)
{
    account[DupeFieldName] = message;
    account["new_approved"] = false;
}
```

And in my form, I have put this event handler on the `onChange` event of the `new_approval_status`:

```
function dupeDetected(context) {

    var dupeStatus = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('new_approval_status').getValue();

    if (!dupeStatus || dupeStatus == '') {
        Notify.remove('duplicateWarning'); //Notify is a library that adds notification at form level...
        return;
    }

    var messageParts = dupeStatus.split('|');
    var message = messageParts[1];
    var fieldName = messageParts[0];

    Notify.add(message, 'ERROR', 'duplicateWarning', null);

};
```

This triggers fine when `new_approval_status` goes from null, empty to something. But it doesn't trigger on the other way around, a string to an empty string or null.

In my plugin, I've tried setting `new_approval_status` to `string.Empty` or `null` but the event doesn't trigger that way around.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set your field to something like `OK` instead.

This also allows to guarantee your code works ("is the field empty because it's supposed to be, or something is missing and it isn't being filled ?")

Comment: How did I not think of that is beyond me. Thanks Alex.